# struts2/jsp - name for property, which is list of list

Tags: jsp, struts2

My action contains property, which is list of list:

```
List<ArrayList<Pair>> selectedId;
```

Class Pair has two fields: first and second.

And I try to set value for this property from jsp page:

```
<s:hidden value="567" name="selectedId[0][0].first"/>
```

but after form submit I get a error:

> ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: java.util.ArrayList.first

How do this in right way?

Comment: How can you access the selectedId as array?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that OGNL assigns `name="selectedId[0][0].first"` for element at selectedId.get(0).get(0)

Just try something like:

```
<s:iterator value="selectedId" status="stat">
 <s:iterator>
    <s:textfield value="%{#stat}"/>
 </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

And get the assigned name of the field using Firebug or some tools. If the name you assigned was right, there must be some problem with property named "first".

Because `s:iterator` uses keyword "first" to check if the current elements is the first in the collection.

You can see it from here:

http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-iterator-tag-example1.html

Hope this helps.